# IEnumerable skip and take

Tags: c#, generics

I have a custom control with a data source of type IEnumerable (non-generic). Now I want to implement paging on the data source, and so I need something like Skip and Take, which List-of-T has. Right now I am using the following:

```
List<object> pagingList = DataSource.Cast<object>().ToList()
```

This can be inefficient, I'm guessing, so I'm looking for a better way to do this. Enumerating the collection, skipping elements and such with two counters might be more efficient, but it's so ugly I just don't want to do it. But maybe it's the best choice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why are you calling `ToList()`? You can use `Skip` and `Take` without that:

```
IEnumerable<object> paged = DataSource.Cast<object>()
                                      .Skip(page * pageSize)
                                      .Take(pageSize);
```

That will save converting the whole data source to a list - but it *does* mean you can't skip efficiently when the source isn't an `IList<T>`.

Two important questions though:

- You mention that you *guess* your original code is inefficient... have you measured? How big is this data, and what's its form in memory? What else are you doing with it? Is this really a bottleneck? Collect facts rather than guessing.
- It would be easier to use your data in various ways if you had a generic data source... is that something you could achieve?

Comment: Ok, so now I'm down to creating just one extra copy :) Thanks!

Comment: @EladLachmi: I'm not sure what you mean. Iterating over the query above won't create an in-memory copy of the whole page. It will just yield the values one at a time.

Comment: No, I have not measured, but just skipping the list conversion made this question worth asking. I don't need to measure to know that... :) I would use a generic type if I could, but I can't...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will be too inefficient, given the way the LINQ extension methods are implemented.  If you really wanted to, you could implement extension methods to IEnumerable for `Skip()` and `Take()`, but I don't think it's necessary.

It's a good idea to try the method where the code makes the most sense to someone reading it, and then go back and change it if you find it performs inadequately and a profiler says that this section is the culprit.